# How Can I Call an API with mutiple Lists as parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, api, asp.net-web-api

Maybe My Question sounds different but I'm trying to do something unique.
I'm trying to make an API call like this :-

```
public List<TableRecordsEntity> GetTableRecordsList(string ListType, List<string> stringColumnNames, List<string> stringColumnValues, List<int> intValueParams)
    {
        List<TableRecordsEntity> lstTableRecordsEntity = new List<TableRecordsEntity>();
        var baseAddress = "Base";
        using (HttpClient client = LocalUtility.InitializeHttpClient(baseAddress))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "/GetTableRecordsList?ListType=" + ListType + "&stringColumnNames=" + stringColumnNames + "&stringColumnValues=" + stringColumnValues + "&intValueParams=" + intValueParams).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                lstTableRecordsEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableRecordsEntity>>(data);
            }
        }
        return lstTableRecordsEntity;
    }
```

Now I don't know how to access the API as I'm not able to make it hit the API.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Base/GetTableRecordsList")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTableRecordsList(string ListType, List<string> stringColumnNames, List<string> stringColumnValues, List<int> intValueParams)
    {
        return Ok(_repository.GetTableRecordsList(ListType, stringColumnNames, stringColumnValues, intValueParams));
    }
```

Can I do something like this or can I not? If yes then what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

By convention you don't send data in a GET request, all data should be passed via the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify [FromUri] in the method's parameter. Web API expecting it to come from the Request body by default. You can add the [FromUri] like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromUri]List<string> stringColumnNames)
{
   return Ok(_repository.GetTableRecordsList(stringColumnNames));
}
```

add call like this

```cs
http://localhost:59511/api/Values?str[]="abc"&str[]="xyz"
```